# Bind column width of grid from two itemtemplates

Tags: wpf, xaml

In one XAML window, I have two seperate `ItemsControls` for different `ViewModels`. The `ItemsControls` both have grids where the first columns should be the same width. Right now I have the following, but the grids just manage their size independently. I want the first columns to be the same width. Here is my XAML

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="x">
    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ItemsControl Name="inputs1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="1" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Description}" />
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>

      <Grid Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ItemsControl Name="inputs2" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="1" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Description}" />
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

They have the same sharedsizegroup so they should be equal right? 
Result now: https://gyazo.com/2284485127427673269dfd8e26e42682

Comment: Do you have Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" on a parent control that contains both grids?

Comment: Well good luck at finding an answer. pastebin is proxy-blocked for me currently. Also, its pretty easy: create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then it will fit into your question and it will be small enough so people are actually motivated to help you.

Comment: @grek40 did an update with the complete code minified as much as posible, hope that might help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` properties in the lower hierarchy levels and only keep it in the control that spans all your involved grids. It seems that for each of these properties, a new shared scope is opened, so higher level scopes are ignored (though I couldn't really read that from documentation).